# Form Control Passing A Function Returns Null

Tags: c#, events, textbox, nullreferenceexception

I have several textbox, and need to be validated data should be 0 and 100 integer.

For that reason i have created a class class TextBoxChecker in that class there is member function TextBoxLeave which is used to check textbox value between 0 and 100.

```
 public void TextboxLeave(ref object sender, EventArgs e, ErrorProvider err,string message)
 {
        if ((sender as TextBox).Text != "")
        {
            if (Convert.ToDouble((sender as TextBox).Text) >= 0 && Convert.ToDouble((sender as 
           TextBox).Text) <= 100)
                return;
            else
            {
                (sender as TextBox).Focus();
                (err as ErrorProvider).SetError((sender as TextBox), message);
            }
        }
 }
```

The function is used behind a form application  Textbox_Leave Event.

```
    TextBoxChecker checker=new TextBoxChecker();
    private void txtMaxDetect_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checker.TextboxLeave(ref sender, e, this.errProviderKademe, "Value cannot be greater than 
         100");
    }
```

The problem is when pass the sender as a paramter System.NullReferenceExcpetion is thrown even though when i debug the sender Text value is valid.

what can be wrong thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a separate class you can simply paste this piece of code in Leave Event. If you want to make a separate class, i suggest you pass text value as string instead of sender object.